# How to integrate paypal sandbox in php

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to intgrate paypal sandbox in php.

I have code below

```
<?php
$paypalURL = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'; 
$paypalID = 'dnyaneshk8.business@gmail.com'; //Business Email

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>PayPal Standard Payment Gateway Integration by CodexWorld</title>
</head>
<body>
<br/>Name: Movie Kabaali
<br/>Price: 101
<form action="<?php echo $paypalURL; ?>" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypalID;             ?>">

    <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
     <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Kabali movie ticket">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="101">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="2">

    <!-- Specify URLs -->
    <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://localhost/paypal_jatin/cancel.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://localhost/paypal_jatin/success.php'>

    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
    <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
    <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
</form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

This code working but when payment is successful, it not returning to my site immediately.

It is giving message like

```
 you've just completed your payment.
```

And then after that below two links are there

1 . Return to Dyanesh Business's Test Store

2 . Go to PayPal account overview

I want that when transaction successful user should redirected to the localhost.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: That output you share... Is the actual JSON (as shown when e.g. saved to a file) or the result of some dump function?

Comment: What if you return `result_array()` from model. Or try with `json_encode($inbox, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)`.

Comment: That result is actual what I got. @ÁlvaroGonzález I just removed some part because data is too big.

Comment: But strings only exist inside computers, you need to convert them to something physical in order so see them. Where do you see something that starts with `"[{\"msg_by\":`? The Network pane in your browser's developer tools? Your screen as a result of typing `echo $inbox;`? Sorry for asking but I see questions here everyday where people complain about invalid JSON and then happen to have perfectly valid JSON, except that they didn't know how to see it.

Comment: I discovered yesterday that some of the JSON constants are quite new. You should check what version of PHP is running on the server.